# Room Entity Annotation

Tags: java, android, room

В чем проблема? Comple error : Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опубликуйте код текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: И покажите `build.gradle (module app)` - возможно, вы библиотеки не подключили.